# Google+ Custom Sign In Button overridden by iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-plus

I am trying to have a custom styled Google+ sign in button and following Google's docs by using gapi.signin.render should allow me to do so. But even using that the button's style gets replace by an iFrame.

The code im using is simple:

```
var $Button = $("<div>").addClass("SocialGooglePlusLoginButton").appendTo("body");

    gapi.signin.render($Button.get(0), {
        callback: OnSignIn,
        clientid: Configuration.Get("GooglePlusClientID"),
        cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
        requestvisibleactions: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    });
```

Theoretically that should be all i require but it doesn't seem to be enough? What am I missing?

The g+ script is included with the option onload=explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out G+ is scanning the structure of the div and I had to append some empty spans into it before it would work like so:

```
$("<div>").addClass("SocialGooglePlusLoginButton").append($("<span>"), $("<span>"));
```